# Symbolic link directories redirects to itself

Tags: ln, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I created a symbolic link to OneDrive using the following

```
ln -s ~/in_between_directories/OneDrive/ ./onedrive
```

When I cd into onedrive from my working directory it correctly displays the directories inside OneDrive such as Documents and Photos. However, when I try to cd into Documents it displays the same directories even though the path updated to reflect that I am in the Documents directory.

```
~$/ cd onedrive
~/onedrive$ ls
Documents Photos
~/onedrive$ cd Documents
~/onedrive/Documents$ ls
Documents Photos
```

I do not have this problem when I manually cd into OneDrive using it's full path and I am doing this on Bash on Ubuntu on Windows. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide the outputs of `ls -l` while in those directories?

Comment: Outputs in both directories are the same. Here is a sample of the output (excluding personal files).

`total 76`
`drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 0 Feb 12 17:47 Documents`
`drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 0 Jun 14 2016 Pictures`

Answer (score 1):

This was somehow solved by naming the symbolic link "OneDrive". There were no updates or downloads that I believe helped with this issue (I downloaded node and sqlite).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and trying a different name didn't do it for me.

It worked after updating to Windows 10 Creators Update (my current OS build is 15063.540).